# Declare multiple javascript arrays using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to declare multiple arrays using a for loop. This is the code set I tried, But it is not working.

```
function insert_marks(count)
{
    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        var document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value  = new Array();
    }
}
```

document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value` holds the array name.
What should I change?

Modified - I need to declare a set of arrays. The value of count variable is the number of arrays needed to be defined. It changes time to time. As an example if count = 3 I need 3 arrays like this,

var marks_1 = new Array(); var marks_2 = new Array(); var marks_3 = new Array();

Comment: you can't set an input value to an array. How would that behave?

Comment: don't use `new Array()`. Use `[]`

Comment: Your loop body is invalidly attempting to declare a new variable named `document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value`. Then there's the problem of the array being assigned to an element value.

Comment: Are you trying to do `array[ document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value ]` ???

Comment: array name goes as marks_1 , marks_2 likewise.

Comment: ok... document elements are parts of a document (the one that is being shown to the user). Input elements can hold a value (always a string). Javascript variables are a different concept. They can hold (references to) document elements, or they can hold (references to) arrays, but a document element input value is never an array.

Comment: If you want to access a variable by name, it should be a property of some object `var obj={}`. Then you can do `obj[key] = ...`.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - var document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value = [];     didn't work

Comment: @user2590172 I know. What I'm trying to tell you is why.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - okay, now only I understood. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2590172 please tell us what you're _really_ trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the keyword 'var', since you're assigning a value to a an identifier that already exists -- in this case, the return value of getElementById.

Comment: `var` is not the only problem here.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
function insert_marks(count)
        {
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                var val =  document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value;
                eval("var "+val+"=[];");

            }
        }
```

This may help..

Comment: Please don't use `new Array()`. Why are you using it?

Comment: also, `val[j] = new Array()` will overwrite `val[j] = document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value`. It won't affect the value of the element with the ID `mark_set_"+i`

Comment: I have changed my answer.. Maybe this will help.. It will create a variable named document.getElementById('mark_set_' + i).value..

Comment: no. `eval` should be avoided, and variable variables should be avoided. variable variables have messy scoping (right now they won't be visible outside `insert_marks`). Use object properties instead. You'll gain speed, scoping will be clearer, you won't have namespace conflicts, you won't have an injection vector (evaluating the value of a text input is a particularly bad idea)... most importantly, do you know what the asker _really_ wants?